# Building a matrix from a distance matrix

Tags: matrices

Given the following distance matrix

$$D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 & 4\\ 3 & 0 & 5\\ 4 & 5 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

how do I actually do the $D^2_{1j}$ and $D^2_{i1}$ parts, as seen below?

$$M_{ij} = \frac {D^2_{1j}+D^2_{i1}-D^2_{ij}} 2$$

Wouldn't $D_{1j}$ mean the first row of the matrix, so $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$, while $D_{i1}$ would mean the first column of the matrix, so $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$? But you can't really square those since equal rows and columns are needed...

I think that $D^2_{ij}$ means multiplying the entire matrix by itself. Dividing by two is the same as multiplying the scalar 0.5 to the resulting matrix, right?

Sorry, I'm still quite new to matrices, so please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: It just means make $i,j$ vary from $1$ to $3$ and calculate each of the $9$ terms. The formula involves only scalars.

Comment: $D_{ij}$ is the element in row $i$ and column $j$.

Comment: Ohh, so $D^2_{1j}$ means squaring each of the values in the first row, and $D^2_{i1}$ means squaring each of the values in the first column? And $D^2_{ij}$ means squaring each of the values in the entire matrix?

Comment: That is correct.